# How to alt tab to specified window application tab

Tags: powershell, shell

I am trying to make a script to alt tab every X seconds to a specified application window but so far I just managed to make one that alt tabs my 2 most recent tabs, can anybody help me with how i make it to alt tab me to a process name or window application name?

`while($true){ Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('%{TAB}') sleep 5 }`

Comment: It’s going to be almost impossible to bring the *correct* application to the foreground by automating alt-tab keystrokes - how do you know how many tabs you need to send at any given time? If you google your question you’ll find a number of examples of using Powershell to find a process by window title and invoking win32 api calls to bring it to the foreground - e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/12802050/3156906. That has a better chance of working - have a play with some of those and see how far you can get…

Comment: yea I agree, I am trying a different approach with 
$wsh.AppActivate("the app i want")
sleep 5
if ($wsh.AppActivate("nothing")){
$wsh.AppActivate("nothing")} else{
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('%{TAB}')}
sleep 5 

But how can I make it use the current app/window application that I am on a bit more clean since it works that way but it cycles all alt tabs till last one i think or not sure? (in the if function) also sorry if the code looks nasty its my first time using stack and I am not sure yet how to properly write it

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Win** + **[Number]** to open an application from your taskbar directly.

Comment: I don't wanna start an application, I want it to cycle to that specific application tab that is opened already instead of the first 2 most recent tabs at a set interval

Comment: If the application is already open then it will switch to it.

Comment: yes but I want to cycle to it every 6-7 minutes not to just manually swap to it if you understand

Comment: So you can't simulate that cycling with your script by instead of alt tabbing you use win 
 + number?

Comment: No I figured it out how to make it work but the issue is that now I want it to alt tab back to my current tab and I am not sure how it works if you could help me out kindly, here is the script:
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
$wsh = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.shell
while($true){
$wsh.AppActivate("MyAppName")
sleep 0.2
if ($wsh.AppActivate("ecd")){
$wsh.AppActivate("ecd")} else{
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('%{TAB}')}
sleep 460
}